# How to lens onto field of a record which is a polymorphic function?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I just installed the `lens` library so I can easily `set` in a nested data structure. However, i ran into a problem. Here is a minimal example to demonstrate my problem

The following code doesn't compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens    

data MyRecord = MyRecord 
  { _func :: forall . a -> a
  }

makeLenses ''MyRecord

changeMyRecord :: MyRecord -> MyRecord
changeMyRecord r = r & func .~ id
```

The error is `No Instance for (Contravariant Identity) arising from use of 'func'`.

I had a look at `Contravariant`, and I'm pretty sure that it is impossible for me to make this instance since

```
class Contravariant f where
  contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

i.e. If `f = \x -> x` I don't see where i'm going to find something of type `a` to apply to the function argument `(a-> b)`

Is there a different way to modify a `MyRecord` using lenses? Or could I perhaps avoid `RankNTypes` somehow, but still pass around a polymorphic `_func` in my record? Or something else?

Record update syntax is off the cards - imagine that `MyRecord` is deeply nested.

Please assume very little haskell knowledge when answering, in particular I only started looking at the lens library today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lens` is pulling a hack here – it wouldn't be possible to use `func` as a lens (or other write-capable optic) with type

```
func :: Lens' MyRecord (a -> a)
```

because that would mean you can put any concrete-type endofunction in, like

```
changeMyRecord :: MyRecord -> MyRecord
changeMyRecord r = r & func .~ ((+1) :: Int -> Int)
```

So instead, it makes `func` only a getter

```
func :: Getter' MyRecord (a -> a)
```

...which is ok, because a universal-polymorphic function *can* be used on any type, so the following works:

```
useMyRecord :: MyRecord -> String
useMyRecord r = show (r^.func $ 1 :: Int)
```

And seeing that

```
type Getter s a = ∀ f. (Contravariant f, Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

that's where that `Contravariant` constraint comes from. The `No Instance for Contravariant` error message is just VanLaarhoven-Kmett-ish for `Can't use a ‘Getter’ as a ‘Setter’`.

**What you'd actually *want*** to have is of course

```
func :: Lens' MyRecord (∀ a . a -> a)
```

but that's unfortunately an [impredicative type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Impredicative_polymorphism), which Haskell [doesn't support](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ImpredicativePolymorphism). Namely, it would expand to

```
func :: ∀ f . Functor f => ((∀ a . a -> a) -> f (∀ a . a -> a)) -> MyRecord -> f MyRecord
```

Note that there's a `∀` inside the `f`.

To get the semantics of such a polymorphic-field lens, you'll need to wrap that in a Rank-0 type:

```
newtype PolyEndo = PolyEndo { getPolyEndo :: ∀ a . a -> a }

data MyRecord = MyRecord 
  { _func :: PolyEndo
  }

makeLenses ''MyRecord
-- func :: Lens' MyRecord PolyEndo
```